# Javascript objects - Removing and adding items

Tags: javascript, object

I'm still new to Javascript and trying to build a small project, I've done some research online about manipulating objects, but I mostly found forums about filtering arrays and not objects.

I have 2 objects:

```
let Object1 = {item1: {}, item2: {}, item3: {}}
let Object2 = {item4: {}, item5: {}}
const removeItem = 'item1'
```

I need to apply the following on these objects:

1. Remove the item in "removeItem" from Object1 and return a new object:

   Object1 = {item2: {}, item3: {}}
2. Copy item4 from Object2 to Object1 and return a new object:

   Object1 = {item2:(), item3: {}, item4: {}}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the item in "removeItem" from Object1 and return a new object:

```
const newObject = { ...Object1 };
delete newObject[removeItem];
```

2. Copy item4 from Object2 to Object1 and return a new object:

```
const newObject = { ...Object1, item4: Object2['item4'] };
```

Comment: Derp, you're right, @adiga